# How to get python to recognize pip modules

Tags: python, gtk3

I attempted to import a module that I installed using pip into my gtk code, but once I run it I only get an error “ModuleNotFoundError”. It seems that it does not recognize that I even installed the module, Any reason for why this is?

Comment: What command did you use to install module? What version of Python are you using? Add the output of `pip list | grep module` to your question.

Comment: I used Pip3, I am using Python3.8, and it does show up under pip3 list

Comment: Is your code using `pip3` or `pip` to import the module?

Comment: From your description, it sounds like you have multiple versions of Python 3.x.  You mentioned you installed your modules with `pip3`, but did you check that `pip3` is actually using the expected version of Python (3.8) and not a different one?  Please show how you are invoking Python 3 to run your code and also the output of `pip3 -V`.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure you use the right package manager to install a module. You cannot install modules for Python 3 using pip and modules for Python 2 using pip3. If you do, the Python interpreter may not recognize that you have installed a module.

To get details about a package that is currently installed you can use the **`pip show <package>`** command

If the information was helpful please don't forget to up vote or accept the answer.

Comment: Well I did install them with the correct method (they also only support python3) so I don’t think that would be the issue